# Homology groups equal when $\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_n(\mathbb{S}^m) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^m) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I'm reading a [set of notes](http://www.math.ru.nl/~mgroth/teaching/algtopI14/Lecture06.pdf) but I don't understand the following concept. We have a long exact sequence

$\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_n(\mathbb{S}^m) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^m) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$

Apparently this implies that $H_n(\mathbb{S}^m)$ is isomorphic to $H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^m)$. Why is this true? I tried to prove it using exactness and rank nullity but all I could show is that rank$(H_n(\mathbb{S}^m)) = $ rank$(H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^m))$

Comment: Hint: Exactness of $0\to A\to B$ implies $A\to B$ is injective, and exactness of $A\to B\to 0$ implies that $A\to B$ is onto. Check the definition of exactness and it falls right out.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Thanks, I think I've got it. But do you mean the definition of isomorphism?

Comment: No I meant the definition of exactness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be clearer if you actually name the maps. You have a short exact sequence within the long exact sequence
$$
0\xrightarrow{f}H_n(S^m)\xrightarrow{g} H_{n-1}(S^m)\xrightarrow{h} 0
$$
where $f$ and $h$ are zero maps. Then by exactness, $0=\operatorname{im}(f)=\ker g$, so $g$ is injective. Also, $\operatorname{im}(g)=\ker h=H_{n-1}(S^m)$ since $h\equiv 0$. Thus $g$ is surjective, hence an isomorphism.

There is no need to look at the ranks of the groups.

Answer (score -1):

If the coefficients in the sequence are in some field, then you have a linear map between two vector spaces of the same rank. By  exactness, the kernel of the map is trivial, so the map is onto. Now from rank-nullity theorem, the image is n-dimensional subspace of n-dimensional space. Alternatively, if not working over a field. then, by exactness ,the kernel of the $0$ map is $H_{n-1}$, i.e., the whole space, which coincides with the image o the map, so the map is onto 1-1 and linear, i.e., an isomorphism.

Comment: Here the "homology groups" (of spheres) are abelian groups, which are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules but not vector spaces in any canonical sense.

Comment: you can change coefficients and work with fields; I think this preserves the properties of the LES.

Comment: @user99680: Although the tensor product is right-exact (but not left-exact in general), $H_*(X; k)$ is not $H_*(X)\otimes k$ in general; there's an extra $\text{Tor}$ summand. Also, an isomorphism $A\otimes k \to B\otimes k$ does not imply that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, even for $\mathbb{Z}$-modules; for $k = \mathbb{Q}$, for example, $A$ and $B$ could have nonisomorphic torsion.

Comment: O.K, I  have edited.

Comment: So, what is wrong now?

Comment: Thanks for not responding , downvoter.

Comment: no problem, downvoter, I will explain the answer to you one of these days.